# unable to encode  to store in azure database

Tags: azure, encoding, python-unicode

I have a Azure sql server with **collation = SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS**. I want to store some unicode character= with code point as **u'\U0001f381'**. 
I am using python 2.7.11 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

When I encode it using 'utf-8' like

```
u'\U0001f381'.encode('utf-8')
```

it is getting saved as 楧瑦躟 in azure database. I am not sure which encoding should I use before pushing data to database. I am guessing that since my azure database has collation as **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS** I should use some other encoding.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the data type of the column?  (should be nchar or nvarchar)  Also, what does your connection string look like?  are you specifying a character set other than UTF-8?

Comment: @EricPetroelje The data type of the column is nvarchar(MAX). My connection string is    conn = pymssql.connect(host=HOST, user=USER, password=PASSWORD, database=DATABASE). I am not specifying any character set while connecting.